# While implementing google authentication in angular7 application I am getting 403 error code (restricted_client)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I have created an application in angular7 and try to implement google authentication for login with firebase but I am facing some issues.

I tried all possible ways that I'm familiar with but I couldn't reach out to the problem. I am attaching my code here please correct me if I did something wrong.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './check-out/check-out.component';
import { OrderSuccessComponent } from './order-success/order-success.component';
import { MyOrdersComponent } from './my-orders/my-orders.component';
import { AdminProductsComponent } from './admin/admin-products/admin-products.component';
import { AdminOrdersComponent } from './admin/admin-orders/admin-orders.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent,
    CheckOutComponent,
    OrderSuccessComponent,
    MyOrdersComponent,
    AdminProductsComponent,
    AdminOrdersComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { 
        path : "", 
        component : HomeComponent 
      },
      { 
        path : "productos", 
        component : ProductsComponent 
      },
      { 
        path : "shopping-cart", 
        component : ShoppingCartComponent 
      },
      { 
        path : 'check-out', 
        component : CheckOutComponent 
      },
      { 
        path : 'order-success', 
        component : OrderSuccessComponent 
      },
      { 
        path : 'login', 
        component : LoginComponent 
      },
      {
        path : 'my/orders',
        component : MyOrdersComponent
      },
      { 
        path : 'admin/products', 
        component : AdminProductsComponent 
      },
      { 
        path : 'admin/orders', 
        component : AdminOrdersComponent 
      },
      {
        path : '**',
        component : NotFoundComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';  //angularfire2/auth

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent{

  constructor(private afAuth : AngularFireAuth) { }

  login()
  {
     this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
  }

}
```

**login.component.html**

```html
<button 
   (click) = "login()"
   class = "btn btn-success">Login With Google
</button>
```

Comment: Try: Log out of ALL Google accounts you are currently logged into on that machine from within the same browser platform.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: You are using angular2fire instead of @angular/fire in the app module. Is that normal ?